# Question about $I(n)=x^n \cos x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $I(n)=x^n \cos x$, find $I(n)$ in terms of $I(n-2)$.

This is a reduction formula question.

Comment: I think the problem might be $I(n)=\int x^n\cos x dx$.

Comment: *Assuming* that's what you really ask, then $I(n) = x^2I(n-2)$. But clearly see above comment.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no mistake in your question, then the answer is
$$I(n)=x^n \cos(x)=x^2x^{n-2}\cos(x)=x^2 I(n-2)$$

In the case that you actually meant

$$I(n)=\int_0^\pi x^n \cos(x) dx,$$

you can use integration by parts twice, each time integrating the term $x^n$. With other bounds on the integral it works the same way.

Let us assume $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\not=0,1$. Then

$$I(n)=\left[ x^n \sin(x)\right|_0^\pi - n\int_0^\pi x^{n-1} \sin(x) dx$$

Since $\sin(0)=\sin(\pi)=0$, we get

\begin{align}
I(n) &= -n\int_0^\pi x^{n-1} \sin(x) dx = [n x^{n-1}\cos(x)]_0^\pi-n(n-1)\int_0^\pi x^{n-2} \cos(x)dx
\end{align}

Now $\cos(\pi)=-1$, so

$$\boxed{\displaystyle I(n)=-n\pi^{n-1} - n(n-1) I(n-2)}$$

Comment: What is the real question? Is it integral technique by reduction formula?

Answer (score 0):

You have:
$$
I(n)=x^n\cos x,\tag1
$$
then
$$
I(n-2)=x^{n-2}\cos x.\tag2
$$
Divide $(1)$ by $(2)$, you will get
$$
\frac{I(n)}{I(n-2)}=x^2\quad\Rightarrow\quad I(n)=x^2I(n-2).
$$